# SPL not building in Uboot when compiling Uboot

Tags: bootloader, boot, u-boot

I am currently working on Uboot bootloader for booting up from SD Card. I have compiled the uboot with the CONFIG_SPL_BUILD=y enabled and I am not able to see any directory named spl in the uboot home directory or any file like u-boot-spl.bin. I am really confused why something like this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide U-Boot version and the name of the defconfig that you are using. If you are using unmerged patches, provide the URL of your git repository.

Comment: The defconfig we are using is present at https://gitlab.com/shaktiproject/software/uboot/-/blob/sd-support-u-boot/configs/shakti_arty100_defconfig

Comment: I have the the uboot executable compiled and I have loaded into the board and found that it is hanging at hang function (hang () at lib/hang.c:33) which is being called from arch/riscv/cpu/start.S:195 to board_init_f which calls hang based on some macros.

Comment: You use CONFIG_RISCV_SMODE=y. This requires that you start U-Boot from OpenSBI. OpenSBI must provide a device-tree. The best place to get support is via the U-Boot maling list and the #u-boot IRC channel on irc.libera.chat:6697. For OpenSBI questions just ask on the #riscv channel.

Comment: I would like to know why there is 2 different config like qemu-riscv64_defconfig and aqemu-riscv64_spl_defconfig. Is this 2 used to create u-boot proper and u-boot-spl respectively? If so then where to mention the OpenSBI exec for SPL to be generated? Is it possible to use that 2 config as reference to create for a new SoC?

Comment: qemu-riscv64_spl_defconfig is the one that runs with OpenSBI. SPL and OpenSBI run in M-mode and main U-Boot in S-mode. qemu-riscv64_defconfig runs in M-mode.

Comment: Hi @Xypron, Thanks for your explanation. I tried to compile UBoot and pass the u-boot.bin to the OpenSBI while giving the make command which generates the fw_payload.elf. I tried to run the fw_payload.elf in spike I was able to see only the OpenSBI logo and the Board HART details but it seems that the control to the uboot is not passed. I also tried a compilation with FW_PAYLOAD and FW_FDT after which the OpenSBI logo isn't printed on console. Am I missing some linker command or file to start the uboot?

Comment: Please, follow the instructions in https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/board/emulation/qemu-riscv.html#running-u-boot-spl

Comment: Hi @Xypron, Thanks for the support, the U-Boot is starting now. I would like to know if there are any specific reason why the U-Boot sends SIMPLE_TX and SIMPLE_RX to the SPI driver. I am using "mmc-spi-slot" driver for mmc driver over spi. I see that the CMD0 kindof commands come in simplex tx and the response are to be given in next transcation by simplex rx. Is there any specific reason for this method or is it possible to change the SPI core to work in full duplex.

Comment: scripts/get_maintainer.pl -f drivers/mmc/mmc_spi.c provides the maintainers of that code. Don't hesitate to ask via a mail to them and the U-Boot list.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Xypron